# How can I drag a folder/directory item from an NSOutlineView to an app like Finder or Xcode

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nsoutlineview, nspasteboard

I've created an outline view table that shows my disk (file system) hierarchy similar to this example from Apple :

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OutlineView/Articles/UsingOutlineDataSource.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000725-142693

Now I want to be able to drag files/folders from my outline view to other applications that accept drops like Finder, Xcode, iTunes etc. 
These are the functions that I'm implementing for my data source for NSOu

```
let pb: NSPasteboard?
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, writeItems items: [AnyObject], toPasteboard pasteboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool {
    var array = [NSURL]()
    self.pb?.declareTypes([NSFilesPromisePboardType], owner: self)
    if let fileItem = items[0] as? FileSystemItem {
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileItem.getFullPath()!)
        array.append(fileURL)
        self.pb?.addTypes([fileURL.pathExtension!], owner: nil)
        self.pb?.writeObjects(array)
        return true
    }else {
        return false
    }
}
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination dropDestination: NSURL, forDraggedItems items: [AnyObject]) -> [String] {
    var names = [String]()
    if let fileItem = items[0] as? FileSystemItem {
        print(fileItem.getRelativePath())
        names.append(fileItem.getRelativePath()!)
        return names
    }else {
        return names
    }
}
```

I'm currently getting this error in the console

```
Looked for HFSPromises on the pasteboard, but found none.
```

Finally this is a screenshot of what I have -
[NSOutlineView showing file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wapsX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use promises unless the file does not exist and you will create it at a location specified by the recipient. If it is a single file, use NSURLPboardType. For multiple files, use NSFilenamesPboardType.